# In Kakaotalk, what is the meaning of 꼰대 as a notification sound?

Tags: word-usage

I was scrolling the notification sounds in Kakaotalk (English user interface) and saw one listed as: **kkondae**.
I think it should be written as 꼰대, which translates as 'braid'.
But what is meant by this? Not just braid, I guess. Is it slang? I'm completely missing the point of having a notification sound that says out loud and in a deep voice: Braid!

Comment: You can find it [here](https://www.bbc.com/worklife/article/20190726-the-condescending-old-people-of-south-koreas-workforce).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a Korean slang.
https://www.bbc.com/worklife/article/20190726-the-condescending-old-people-of-south-koreas-workforce
https://www.bbc.com/worklife/article/20190718-kkondae
like 'boomer'. You can use it as a swear word.